# java inheritance polymorphism method dungeon monster game

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

I have a homework problem where I have to make an inheritance program that consists of a class called dungeonCharacter, with two child classes Hero and Monster, that have 3 of their own subclasses that have certain differences, etc etc. I am having trouble with the main class dungeonCharacter. here is the description:

```
DungeonCharacter (base - abstract)
contains instance variables that any character in the game will have -- protected access     is ok (NO public access allowed!) 
o name - String
o hit points (how much damage a character can take before it expires) - integer
o attack speed - integer (1 is slowest)
o damage range (minimum and maximum amount of damage a character can do on an 
attack) - two integers
o chance to hit opponent when attacking - double
o anything else you deem necessary
 constructor to initialize instance variables get and set methods as you deem necessary
 an attack method 
o first checks if character can attack (based on chance to hit)
o if it can, a hit in range of minimum to maximum damage is generated and applied to 
opponent -- user should be informed of what happens
o if it cannot, a message should be displayed that says the attack failed
```

here is my code, i am having a hard time really understanding a few things, in particular, the attack method, and the chance of hitting. I dont know how to get started on that and where to go from here. here is my code so far.

```
public abstract class DungeonCharacter {
    protected String name;
    protected int hitPoints;
    protected int speed;
    protected int minRange;
    protected int maxRange;
    protected double chance;

    public DungeonCharacter(String name, int hitPoints, int speed,
int minRange, int maxRange, int chance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hitPoints = hitPoints;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.chance = chance;
    }

    public void setString(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void Attack() {

    }
}
```

please help me understand this and find the necessary code to fulfill the directions, this hwk is very vague in my opinion and Im having a hard time understanding. and the teacher is useless. thanks for helping! if i can just get this written writing the rest should be easy.

Comment: Specific problems and questions are much more likely to be answered. Something generic like this starts to look an awful lot like, "Please do my homework for me." Do you have a particular question or problem?

Comment: in particular it says first checks if character can attack (based on chance to hit) and I dont really understand how to check. if its passed like .80 that means 80% chance of hitting, how do i check if the attack works or not?

Comment: @anthony, in the absence of any hard data, make up your own criteria. As long as its reasonable, and you can justify it on questioning, you should be all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of any hard data, make up your own criteria. As long as its reasonable, and you can justify it on questioning, you should be all set. The fact that the variable is called "chance" to apply damage, indicates to me the presence of a probability distribution, which means that 0.0 means no chance of hitting, and 1.0 means that you can absolutely hit. You can think about it in terms of 0.0 probably means that the character is too far away to damage the enemy. 1.0 means you're standing right in front of the enemy. The amount of damage that you could apply on attack would therefore depend on the chance to attack and the minimum / maximum damage that can be dished out.

```
public void attack() {
    if(chance > 0.0 /* Some arbitrary value */) {
        double damageToApply = minRange + chance*(maxRange - minRange);
        System.out.println("Applying damage: " + damageToApply);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to apply damage, flee!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `double damageToApply = chance*(maxRange - minRange);` should be `double damageToApply = (chance*(maxRange - minRange))+minRange;` . And I assume that you want him to call `java.lang.Math.random()` for the value between 0 and 1. Also, it should scale with the random value and not with `chance`

Comment: @PeterT It seems to me that he needs a "position" class member as well which gives him an (x,y) point relative to other characters. He could then base the value of "chance" on the distance from the closest enemy. That is why I used chance to scale damage, and not some random value. As for the equation, you're right. I missed out the minRange. Typo.

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with position. If you read the specs than it mean the that attack range is just the minimal and maximum amount of damage that is calculated completely random if the character lands a hit. So it's `double damage=0.0; if(chance>Math.random()) damage = Math.random()*(maxRange-minRange) + minRange;`

Comment: @PeterT, i'm sorry, I don't see the word "random" in the OPs post. Am I missing something? While Random is a perfectly valid approach, and you are free to suggest that to the OP, this is my approach. The problem also categorically states: "anything else you deem necessary". I deem position necessary. Feel free to propose your own answer.

Comment: i understand both of what you guys are saying. this is what I mean with directions that are vague. I have it done your way @siddhartha Shankar

Comment: @Siddartha it says `add getters and setters if you deem them necessary` (edit: it also says all the fields that you deem necessary, my bad) it's implied that the chance is evaluated each time an attack happens and I don't see any other way to model chance that with a random number. Also `generate a number between minRange and maxRange` sounds suspiciously like a random value between those two.

Comment: Also, in my experience of playing games, the degree of damage you inflict is not random, but closely related to your proximity to the enemy, the strength of the weapon or magic power, the strength of the enemy, and the presence of other altering entities such as "shields" or "blocking". All I am suggesting is to take position into account. Using Math.Random(..) would be... well... totally random and not very realistic.

Comment: @SiddharthaShankar all of what you just listed is reflected as the simplyfied `chance`. If chance is 1 than the enemy always hits (because 1 is always larger than Math.random()). If it's 0.5 than oyu hit 50% of the time. For the damage it is equally simplified as a value between minRange and maxRange. If those are `75-100` then you'll always deal at least 75 damage. I think that you are interpreting too much into the task based on your experience with games.

Comment: @anthony, thanks. I don't believe your professor is expecting a "correct" answer. He is simply looking for a valid interpretation of the rules and framework that he has provided. Everything else is left to your imagination. Enjoy. :)

Comment: ya you guys can leave it be for now. all these points im bringing up with the professor tomorrow morning, and then maybe, he will finally provide some direction with this and maybe tell me what hes expecting. thanks :)

Comment: @PeterT, yes, but the culmination of all the factors that I mentioned does not produce a random end result. You see, the OP will develop additional characters which will inherit from the base DungeonCharacter. These additional characters may have all of the mentioned additional attributes, making "chance to hit" a very exact value. Again, I respect your opinion on this matter, but this is MY opinion. I am all about details and imagination. Math.Random() will not cut it for me.

Comment: @SiddharthaShankar yes, your interpretation is also valid. I just think that occam's razor doesn't favor it.